# Finite-dimensional vector spaces vs. matrices over a semiring

Tags: ct.category-theory, vector-spaces

The category $\mathbf{Vect}_k$ of vector spaces over some field $k$ is weakly equivalent to the category $\mathbf{V}_k$ whose objects are finite sets $n$, and whose morphisms $m\to n$ are $(m\times n)$-matrices with entries in $k$.

One can replace $k$ by an arbitrary semiring, or commutative semiring $\ell$ and obtain a category $\mathbf{W}_k$. Doing so, much remains; for example, both $\mathbf{V}_k$ and $\mathbf{W}_\ell$ are compact categories. But of course much is lost, e.g. the notion of *rank*.

**Question 1:** List structures, properties, important theorems etc. about $\mathbf{V}_k$ from vector space theory that hold for $\mathbf{W}_\ell$.

**Question 2:** List structures, properties, important theorems etc. about $\mathbf{V}_k$ from vector space theory that *do not* hold for $\mathbf{W}_\ell$.

Comment: Maybe you should mention that for rings $R$ this is the full subcategory of finite free $R$ modules.  And a lot of how similar the category of matrices is to the category of vector spaces has to do with how close free $R$ modules are to all $R$ modules

Comment: The questions are no questions (grammatically). And they are very broad exercises. For mathoverflow one may expect more focus, motivation and own thoughts.

Comment: You might find https://mathoverflow.net/a/355591/30392 useful: the weak equivalence between linear transformations and matrices passes to free bisemimodules over general semirins (and thus to free semimodules over commutative semirings).